# Gregorian Calendar in C

Tags: c

I really don't know much about c program so really need your help.. 
This is the program to find the day of input value(ex. 1583.3.31 -> Thursday) and print "Wrong year/month/day" if it is unvalid date.
I wrote return 0; in the middle part because I have to get out from this when the date is unvalid. I checked it works. But eventhough when the date is valid (ex. 1583.3.31) it doesn't go to the next part(should print day if number is valid) It just ends the program. I wonder why:(

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int year, month, day;

printf("Enter Gregorian year (year >= 1583): ");
scanf("%d", &year);

printf("Enter Gregorian month (month: 1..12): ");
scanf("%d", &month);

printf("Enter Gregorian day (1..28|29|30|31): ");
scanf("%d", &day);

{if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    printf("Wrong month! Try again!");
if (year < 1583)
    printf("Enter year >= 1583! Try again!");
if (day < 1 || day > 31)
            printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
if (month == 4 && (day < 1 || day > 30))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
if (month == 6 && (day < 1 || day > 30))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
if (month == 9 && (day < 1 || day > 30))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
if (month == 11 && (day < 1 || day > 30))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
if (month == 2){
    if (year % 4 == 0 && (day < 1 || day > 29))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
    if (year % 100 == 0 && (day < 1 || day > 28))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
    if (year % 400 == 0 && (day < 1 || day > 29))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");}
else if (month == 2 && (day < 1 || day > 28))
        printf("Wrong day! Try again!");
return 0;}

year += 8000;

if (month < 3) { year--; month += 12; }

long julian = (year*365) + (year/4) - (year/100) + (year/400) - 1200820 + (month*153+3)/5 - 92 + (day-1);

switch(julian % 7){
    case 0:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Monday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Tuesday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Wednesday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Thursday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Friday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Saturday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("%d-%d-%d is Sunday", year -= 8000, month, day);
        break;}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unconditional `return 0;` after the `if` statements. All but the first `if` should be an `else if` and the code for the correct date should be in an `else` block.  Alternatively, return at the end of every error case, proceeding only if each check passes—although this will lead to a lot of duplication.

Enclosing all those statements in a single set of braces merely creates a lexical scope for variable declarations, probably not what you meant.

The code to check validity could instead be a `do` ... `while` loop that retries while you enter invalid dates, and you should calculate the day of the week after you fall through that loop, which will happen when the date is valid.